# is_front_page only works in theme file, and does not work in functions.php

Tags: themes, frontpage

If I use is_front_page() in my front-page.php file it works as expected. However if I use the same function in my theme functions.php file it does not work. Is this normal behavior? If not can it be trouble shot somehow?

In settings->reading I have my front page set to a page called "front page" so I think that is all set.

**EDIT**

adding the following to functions.php does not work, however I promise it does work as expected if I add is_home_page() to my header.php file

```
add_action('init', 'my_test');

function my_test(){
    if(is_front_page())
        echo 'is it?';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That may be normal behavior, depending on how exactly you're using `is_front_page` in your functions file.

If you use it inside the global scope of `functions.php`, it will not work.

Why? Because WordPress loads `functions.php` before the `$wp_query object` has been set up with the current page.  `is_front_page` is a wrapper around around `$wp_query->is_front_page()`, and if the query hasn't been set up, it's always going to return false (or throw a warning, if you have `wp_debug` on.

From the codex:

> Warning: You can only use conditional query tags after the init action
>   hook in WordPress. For themes, this means the conditional tag will
>   never work properly if you are using it in the body of functions.php,
>   i.e. outside of a function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: I think that's the second time today that we've posted exactly the same answer, at exactly the same time. So, as with the other one, an upvote for you. :)

Comment: Ha, I didn't notice the other one! back at you!

Comment: see my comment above. Adding the function to the init action does not work either. I also tried 'plugins_loaded" as Chip suggested but that does not work either.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  You can always hook in later: `template_redirect` for example.

Comment: I need to remove_action() if the user is viewing the front page. The best place to do this is in functions.php, but that seems easier said than done.

Comment: remove what action? If it's something on the page (within the template)... https://gist.github.com/1782696

Comment: **Exactly** what action are you trying to remove (provide the `add_action()` call that adds the action)?

Comment: It is a custom action added by another plugin... template_redirect seems to work for this one. Not sure how it will work for other scenarios tho.

Comment: It should work about the same -- just always hook in late. Template Redirect is always a safe bet for modifying anything on the front end.  It fires right before WP includes the template. Keep in mind the codex (and your experience now!) says "after the init action hook".

Answer (score 11):

The codex quote by [chrisguitarguy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/6035/chrisguitarguy) is no longer valid!! It has been updated to:

> Warning: You can only use conditional query tags **after** the posts_selection action hook in WordPress (**the *wp* action hook is the first one through which you can use these conditionals**). For themes, this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are using it in the body of functions.php, i.e. outside of a function.

Thus, the *init* hook no longer works!!! As stated, the *wp* hook is the first hook you can use if you want to use conditional query tags. So, to make conditional tags work, here is the minimal boilerplate:

```
add_action('wp', 'function_that_uses_conditional_tags');

function function_that_uses_conditional_tags() {
    // place code here
}
```

However, please note that while that "warning" seems universally applicable to conditional tags as it appears in the very introduction to the codex page about [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), it fails to emphasize that it really only applies to the frontend.

The *wp* hook does not even fire in the backend! So if you use it for instance with is_admin(), it will never evaluate to *true*. Use a different hook in that case. Actually, *init* works just fine for is_admin() ;).

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior. The `functions.php` file is parsed before the query is setup and available, so if you have `if ( is_front_page() )` sitting naked inside of `functions.php`, it will return false, because there's no query yet.

What you need to do is to put your `is_front_page()` conditional *inside of a callback function*, that is then [*hooked into an appropriate action*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) - i.e. an action that fires *after* the query is setup/available.

For reference, I *think* `functions.php` is parsed at `plugins_loaded` (it *might* be `setup_theme`), and the query conditionals should be available at or after `init`.

#### Edit

> plugins_loaded and setup_theme do not work for me

Of *course* those hooks won't work for you. They fire **before the query is setup**. The `is_front_page()` conditional is only available **after the query is setup**, which happens at **`init`**.

> I need to remove_action() if the user is viewing the front page.

You're not really telling us **exactly** what you're trying to do. Your question simply asked when `is_front_page()` available, which is what we answered. Knowing how/when to remove an action is a mostly entirely different question. You need to provide the `add_action()` call you're wanting to remove.

Comment: plugins_loaded and setup_theme do not work for me.

Comment: You need to clarify **exactly what you want to do**. Your example code in your question edit isn't really helpful. For one, you can't echo anything at `init`; for another, clearly, that's not what you're *really* after.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: `is_front_page()` does **not** work at `init` but works on `wp`

Answer (score 2):

The earlier hooks that template_tags are working is `wp` action hook. All hooks before that one like `init` hook won't work for template tags like is_front_page()